# Checked icon color in filter style Material Components Chip (Android)

Tags: android, styles, material-components-android, android-chips

I have the style for the Chip defined as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/TagChip</item>
</style>

<style name="TagChip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter">
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="checkedIconTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/tag_chip_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

And this produces the following results:

[image]

I want to change the black checkmark icon to white.

I've tried changing the `checkedIconTint` property, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: what is drawable/ic_check_circle_white?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti it's a customer drawable. It's in there by mistake; now removed. Looking for a way to do it without using custom drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the checkedIcon programmatically like this

```
 chip.checkedIcon?.let {
        val wrappedDrawable =
            DrawableCompat.wrap(it)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED)
        chip.checkedIcon = wrappedDrawable
    }
```